# Shiny Ggvis Interactivity

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have a plot with ggvis in my shiny app, my question is if I can click on a point of the plot and after that ... do something like in my case, fill a table with information about this point.

Thank you

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: You can also use base-plots and `ggplot2`: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-advanced.html